# VAR model: good diagnostics but poor forecasting performance

Tags: forecasting, vector-autoregression, diagnostic

I constructed a VAR model of order 4 where some of the variables are statistically insignificant. The model is based right in terms of diagnostics (no autocorrelation of residuals, normal distribution, homoskedasticity). I then removed the statistically insignificant variables and computed forecasts.

However, when I evaluate the quality of forecasts using root mean square error (RMSE), I obtain very high values; for example, the response variable has values around 100 while RMSE comes in at around 50.

Is it possible?
How to solve such a conflict: I have good model and such poor forecasts?
Did I make mistake somewhere?

Comment: By "good model" how did you ascertain that? Also, if you only want to use significant variables, you should rebuild your model by applying restrictions.

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 2):

Some variables are intrinsically harder to predict than others. Even if you build a model following all the best-practice guidelines, you may not always accurately predict a process just because it contains a large component of randomness. RMSE values by themselves do not tell the whole story.

However, you may sensibly evaluate the forecasting performance by taking into account

1. subject-matter knowledge (e.g. stock returns are really hard to predict);
2. related studies (can you match or beat their forecast accuracy?);
3. simple benchmarks (does your model of choice do at least as well as a simple benchmark model?).